# How to customize the alignment of text and button inside ion-button?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, button

I would like ask an assistance on how I will customize the alignment of the *text* and *button*  inside `ion-button`. The image below is the sample layout that I want to achieve (based on the wireframe). While the actual output is the 2nd image. I tried the codes below but it is not working. Please refer the codes below,. Hope you can help me because my deadline is ticking critically. Still not yet resolve. Please help me. :(. Thank you

**Based on the wireframe**

[image]

**My actual output**

[image]

**.html**

```
<ion-col
  *ngFor="let link of usefulLinks;let a = index"
  size="12"
  size-lg="6"
>
  <ion-button
    class="link-button"
    (click)="gotoAddresslink(link)"
    icon-end
  
    size="large"
    shape="round"
    color="tertiary"
  >
  <div>
    <p text-align="left" class = "address-title btn-work">{{ link.addressTitle }}</p>
  </div>
    
  <div class="parentElement">
   <img slot="end"
      src="{{'btn.svg'|staticpath}}"
    />
  </div>
  </ion-button>
</ion-col>
```

**.scss**

```
div.parentElement{
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 2px;
 }

 .btn-work{
  letter-spacing: 0.133333px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: inline; 
  top: calc(50% - 19px/2 + 19.5px);
  padding-left: 2px;

 }

.link-button {
   font-family: $fontPrimary;
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 500;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 22px;


   display: flex;
   text-align: left;

   color: $denim-blue;
 }

.address-title {
  font-family: $fontPrimary;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;

 }
```

Comment: Create a Codessandbox demo out of it for me to debug.

Comment: @m4n0 sorry I am not familiar with Codesandbox

Comment: @Green I  also tried to add `float:right` but still not working :(

Comment: I tried fixing the length of text or label and give some flex property. `ion-label{
         width: 200px;
        display: flex;
        align-self: flex-start;
        
      }` Similarly adjust the icon... It worked for me